# Is there a meaningful measure on analytic functions?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{B}$ be the functions analytic on the unit disk and continuous on its boundary. With the supremum norm this becomes a Banach space.

Is there any way to define a meaningful measure on this space?

By meaningful I mean a measure such that any open set has non-zero measure. Basically my problem is that I have a functional, $F$, defined on that space and I know that $F(0)$ is non-zero. I know that the functional is analytic on the space and I would like to say that it is non-zero almost everywhere on $\mathcal{B}$. Is such statement possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This space is separable. Let $(q_n ) $ be a dense subset of $\mathcal{B} .$ Define a measure $\mu : 2^{\mathcal{B}} \to \mathbb{R} $ by $$\mu (A) =\sum_{\{n: q_n \in A\}} 2^{-n}. $$